# how to get logs in DD/MM/YYYY format and ipaddress format using rsyslog in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ubuntu-12.04, syslog, syslogd

```
Feb 4 10:32:57 master sshd[2070]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0) 

Feb 4 10:32:59 master sshd[2070]: Received disconnect from 192.168.0.107: 11: disconnected by user
```

this is some of my system logs what i want is i need logs in format like below

> Feb **04**  **2013** 10:32:57 **192.168.10.10** :sshd[2070]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)

the changes are in bold. i need bold format.

also if we are a server machine and if we are fetching logs from 2 clients then how to store that logs in separately that is something like client1 logs in clientone dir and clienttwo logs in client2 dir by using rsyslog.conf is this possible

Comment: Have you looked through `man rsyslog.conf`? What have you tried?

Comment: i just need that bold for my log analyzer project for faster searching like year wise, date wise, month wise

Comment: You can get the bold by usin a perl parser with `Term::ANSIColor`. I would be happy to provide the parser if you can find out how to change the log format.

Comment: yeah i want to change my log format which already i have shown in bold format

Comment: see my current log format in first line whatever changes i need is instead of master=192.168.10.10 , 4 = 04 and 2013 year is added like this format